# Sum of values filtering for date and label

Tags: excel

i have this table:

[image]

[image]

How i can filter for date (`column B`) then for label (`column D`) and sum value (`column F`).
For example i want sum all values related to month `february` and label `Option2`. The result of this sum should be: `80` (30+40+10). How i do it?

With this:

```
=SUM.IF($D$3:$D$10; "=" & $C$19; $F$3:$F$10)
```

I sum all values with label `Option2`. But i want apply too filter for specific month for example february (date from xx/02/xxxx to end of month only.
Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

how about:

```
=SUMIFS (sum_range, range1, criteria1, [range2], [criteria2], ...)
G3 = SUMIFS($F$3:$F$10,$B$3:$B$10,B3,$D$3:$D$10,D3)
```

and drag the formula down.

Comment: Hello, so not work. I need filter for date then for label then sum values interested. To formula with sum.if i want add filter for month.

Comment: Using label "february" (cell: b19) i want take all date of february (column B) which include from 01/02/2020 until to end month 28/02/2020 (format: DD/MM/YYYY).

Comment: I am not at home, will try and respond later

Comment: The answer below get's you what you want I think!

Answer (score 0):

Try this (with `ctrl` +`shift` + `enter`) being an array formula

```
=SUM((TEXT($B$3:$B$10, "MMMM")=B19)*($D$3:$D$10=C19)*($F$3:$F$10))
```

The formula will be wrapped around curly braces automatically.  It works on my sheet (see screenshot)

[image]